# Sklearn Pipelines - Feature Engineering

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I wrote a simple generic XGBoost classifier code that runs with a pipeline. This is the code (with simple config example):

```
import optuna
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# CONFIG
TEST_SIZE = 0.2
RANDOM_STATE = 42
HYPER_PARAMS_TRIALS = 50
CSV_PATH = "path/to/your/data.csv"
OUTPUT_PATH = "path/to/your/model_output.pkl"
TARGET_COL = "target_column"
CAT_COLS = ["cat_column_1", "cat_column_2"]
NUM_COLS = ["num_column_1", "num_column_2"]

df = pd.read_csv(CSV_PATH)


def optimize_params_xgb(trial):
    max_depth = trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 3, 20)
    reg_alpha = trial.suggest_float("reg_alpha", 0.1, 2.0)
    reg_lambda = trial.suggest_float("reg_lambda", 0.1, 2.0)
    n_estimators = trial.suggest_int("n_estimators", 10, 1000)
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 0.01, 0.3)

    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                               ('classifier', XGBClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth,
                                                            learning_rate=learning_rate, reg_alpha=reg_alpha,
                                                            reg_lambda=reg_lambda))])
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(df[CAT_COLS + NUM_COLS], df[TARGET_COL],
                                                      test_size=TEST_SIZE, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
    pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return roc_auc_score(y_val, pipeline.predict_proba(X_val)[:, 1])


num_preprocessor = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
cat_preprocessor = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
                                   ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[('num', num_preprocessor, NUM_COLS), ('cat', cat_preprocessor, CAT_COLS)])

study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
study.optimize(optimize_params_xgb, n_trials=HYPER_PARAMS_TRIALS)

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('classifier', XGBClassifier(**study.best_params))])
pipeline.fit(df[CAT_COLS + NUM_COLS], df[TARGET_COL])

pickle.dump(pipeline, open(OUTPUT_PATH, 'wb'))
```

But I need the ability to add also feature engineering columns. example:

```
df['num_column_4'] = df['num_column_3'] * 5
df['num_column_5'] = df['num_column_1'] + df['num_column_2'] + df['num_column_4']
df['num_column_6'] = df['num_column_1'] + df['num_column_2'] + df['num_column_3']
```

I created a CustomFeatureEngineering class:

```
class CustomFeatureEngineering(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
      return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
       X = X.copy()
       X['num_column_4'] = X['num_column_3'] * 5
       X['num_column_5'] = X['num_column_1'] + X['num_column_2'] + X['num_column_4']
       X['num_column_6'] = X['num_column_1'] + X['num_column_2'] + X['num_column_3']
       return X
```

But have problems integrating it into the code.

Thanks

Comment: we need more info what you want to do. what return and wich?

Comment: currently, the X columns for the model training and prediction are: ["cat_column_1", "cat_column_2"] and (with oneHotEncoder) also
 ["num_column_1", "num_column_2"]. I want that the X column will also include the feature engineering  columns: 'num_column_4', 'num_column_5', 'num_column_6'.

Comment: ok, but what is error? you need feature engineering 'num_column_4', 'num_column_5', 'num_column_6'  before pipline.

Comment: My question is how to integrate the feature engineering into the pipeline, as the same way I convert the categorical columns to oneHot as part of the pipeline.

Comment: @ZagGol: Have you been able to test the code I prodived in my answer? Does it help you? Is anything unclear? Can I provide more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

To add the feature engineering into the pipeline, just add it as a named step:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('feature_engineering', CustomFeatureEngineering()),
                           ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                           ('classifier', XGBClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth,
                                                        learning_rate=learning_rate, reg_alpha=reg_alpha,
                                                        reg_lambda=reg_lambda))])
```

Remember you need to add the newly created columns to your list of columns:

```
# Define your original columns
NUM_COLS = ["num_column_1", "num_column_2", "num_column_3"]
CAT_COLS = ["cat_column_1", "cat_column_2"]

# Define your new columns
NEW_NUM_COLS = ["num_column_4", "num_column_5", "num_column_6"]

# Update NUM_COLS
NUM_COLS = NUM_COLS + NEW_NUM_COLS
```

Otherwise you only convert your original numeric columns and ignore the newly created ones.